# How to calculate confidence interval in h2o4gpu XGBClassifier?

Tags: python-3.x, h2o4gpu

With GPU h2o, I get the following output from a prediction:

```
model.predict(data)

False
```

I am looking for something similar to the CPU version where the output is:

```
model.predict(data)

predict     False   True
False   0.316711    0.683289
```

I want to view the confidence interval of the prediction for GPU h2o.  What do I need to do?

Comment: Confidence score*

Comment: I figured out the issue.  h2o4gpu uses the same structure as scikit-learn.  i changed predict to predict_proba(data) and probabilities were returned

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. h2o4gpu uses the same structure as scikit-learn. i changed predict to predict_proba(data) and probabilities were returned